# mysql split field value and check condition

Tags: mysql, split, conditional-statements

I have table column values like this,

```
10#9
10#2
10#9
18#10
16#1
11#2
```

I have to find the occurrence of 10

query like

```
select count(*) from table name where field_value= 10
```

Comment: does 10#9 match? and 18#10 also match? and what if you have 10#10, you just have to count one?

Comment: When you have anything-separated fields in a database 99999 out of 100000 you really need to fix your database before doing anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you need something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable
WHERE
  CONCAT('#', field_value, '#') LIKE '%#10#%'
```

This will count all rows where field_value contains 10, but not rows that contains for example 110, eg.

```
10#1   will match
18#10  will match
11#110 won't match
```

Comment: Hi fthiella,Yes im facing one problem now... I have two columns like the above i mentioned, for eg: 10#18 9#10 and correspondingly Yes#ans yes#no.... What this means is if you consider the 10, 18 and 9 as question ID and has multiple answers, i have to count the answer **yes** for question 10... how can we do this... SELECT count(*) from tablename where question_id=10 and answer=yes

Comment: @SathishKumar you can use string lowercase and replace, refer this tutorial link you can understand https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-lower-function.php